# RelayQL: Invalid fragment composition

Tags: relayjs

I'm getting `` Invariant Violation: RelayQL: Invalid fragment composition, use `${Child.getFragment('name')}`. `` in the following. I've no idea why, and nothing seems to fix it. My component contains:

```js
fragments: {
  album: () => Relay.QL`
    fragment on Album {
      ${AlbumMutation.getFragment('album')}
    }
  `,
},
```

AlbumMutation contains:

```js
static fragments = {
  album: () => Relay.QL`
    fragment on Album {
      id
    }
  `,
}
```

Comment: That looks about right. Can we see the entire component, container definition, and mutation, or at least more of them?

Comment: If you can use the Relay Playground to whip up a minimal test case, we'd be happy to take a look: https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html

Answer (score 2):

To anybody who runs into this, its probably due to the examples loading the React, Relay, and ReactDOM libs in the `public/index.html` file, instead of using the webpack `import X from 'y';`.  If you are attempting to use the react-relay-router library, you have to use the latter, but having two copies of Relay will cause this error to occur.

I was able to fix this by removing the references in `public/index.html`, but its good to know that double-importing relay does seem to break this!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this in ES6 by removing my React/Relay imports from the component.

<del>import React from 'react';</del>
<del>import Relay from 'react-relay';</del>

class ...